# How to fix the issue with google authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0

I use @react-oauth/google library. When I start my application in localhost everything works fine. I click on a sign up with google button, after that choose the account to authorize with and it works. But on domain it does not work properly. It shows me popup window, where I can choose the account and after that nothing happens. I used onNonOAuthError function in order to catch the error and it shows me this in the console(first image), but still opens the google popup window. And there is one more thing. When I start my app in localhost and click sing up with google button I see this error(second image), but in localhost it still works.
[in domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQxFu.png)
[in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxqIY.png)